# react component re rendered multiple times when trying to invoke itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

code:

```
myMethod = () => {
 setTimeout(()=> {
 if(!this.state.otherFuncHasBeenCalled) {
    this.myMethod()
 }
},5000)
}
```

so the `otherFuncHasBeenCalled` state is set to true if my other function is called. but what I wanted to do here is when `myMethod` is invoked, after 5 seconds, if my other function is NOT called that sets `otherFuncHasBeenCalled` state to true, invoke `myMethod` again. But it re renders the component multiple times. Help?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
myMethod = () => {
  setTimeout(()=> {
   if(!this.state.otherFuncHasBeenCalled) { // wait 5 sec for check
    this.setState(
      {otherFuncHasBeenCalled: true}, // update state
      this.myMethod  // run again after state has been set
   }
  },5000)
}
```